# AmbiguousMatchException when Binding to default property in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

The following XAML produces an AmbiguousMatchException.  The DataContext for myText is a DataTable consisting of > 1 row which contains a DataColumn named "test":

```
<TextBox Name="myText" Text="{Binding Path=Rows[0].Item[test]}"/>
```

When I modify the binding path syntax to the below example, the binding works as expected:

```
<TextBox Name="myText" Text="{Binding Path=Rows[0][test]}"/>
```

Given that the name of the DataTable is "myData", both of the following lines of code reference the contents of the column "test" on row 0:

```
myData.Rows(0)("test")    
myData.Rows(0).Item("test")
```

Why doesn't the syntax that explicitly names the Item property appear to work in a binding scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Indexed properties when parts of collection have different way of being evaluated in xaml binding then they are when called from code.